# Nginx: deny 'orderby=rand' wordpress url

Tags: sql, wordpress, nginx, sql-order-by

I want to block url 'http://example.com/?orderby=rand' on my websites by nginx.

I thought it'll be easy (like i've blocked 'wp-admin' section). But this code doesn't work, and i don't know why:

```
location ~* \orderby=rand {
    deny all;
}
```

This is very slow and consumes a resource feature of Wordpress.

Comment: Why do you want to block this parameter value?

Comment: Easy Dos-attack any wordpress website.

Comment: That sounds like it would easily be defeated by using a caching plugin. If you really want to disable it though, I still feel like this is only a workaround. Of course you're free to do this, and it's probably gonna work fine, but IMHO it's a better idea to use this as a temporary workaround only and create a feature request ticket on [WordPress Trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/) to add a configuration option to disable random post sorting.

Comment: It cannot be cached - this is a 'rand' mysql feature by design.

Comment: I'm not talking about caching anything in the database, I'm talking about caching generated HTML pages with a Wordpress plugin, like https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-fastest-cache/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **location** directive doesn't match the query string at all. You need to reference the $args variable using an if statement.

```
if ($args ~ orderby=rand) {
   #action
}
```